# Create use via OfficeSIP server in my windows 7 pc but it did not show user online

Tags: windows, operating-system, webserver, windows-server-2008

I am new in `OfficeSIP server` setup. I face some problem. I try google but i do not found any solution. I setup `OfficeSIP server` in my windows 7 pc (laptop) but In laptop do not run `windows server os`.

`I follow this link to setup` http://www.officesip.com/support.html.

After setup i create a user but it show user is off-line.

[image]

```
Now My question is: 
 1. windows server os need to run OfficeSIP server.
 2. Need any more windows configuration to run OfficeSIP server.
 3. I do not configuration DNS server. This configuration are make any problem.
 4. Give me any web url or like to set by set guide to setup OfficeSIP server.
```

Answer (score 1):

1. no, any windows with .net 3.5 SP1
2. no
3. no
4. http://www.thewindowsclub.com/set-up-sip-server-windows , http://www.youtube.com/user/sipreview

Which sip client do you use?

Comment: Before post this question i follow this url. I want to use it for android sip application. any help for me and give me step by step guide line. That help me more. Thanks

Comment: The user status in control panel is supported for [MS-PRES] protocol (used in officesip messenger). Have you any errors when login?

Comment: When i create a use via .cvs menu. it show create user status offline. any problem..